# One moment in time vs. One moment of time

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could be any difference between one moment in time and one moment of time?

There is only one difference: in and of

Comment: Yes, there could be a difference. Did you use a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do our best to avoid any [philosophical questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes) about the nature of "moments," and let's assume that you know the difference between "in" and "of."

The short answer is: No, there's no significant difference.

The long answer is there maybe *ought* to be a difference, or there is if you think hard enough, but they're so similar because of the ways we talk about "time."

When we way "a moment **in** time," we are talking about "time" as a stream, a "timeline" in which individual events can be located. We do this often—"earlier in time," "at the same time." Here, the word "in" works the same as "a room **in** a house."

When we say "a moment **of** time," we are talking about time as if it is a substance and we can measure out certain amounts of it. We do this often as well—"it will take a short time," "a lot of time passed." Here, "of" works the same as "a cup **of** flour."

Since a moment "of" time is also positioned "in" time, we see little difference in the two phrases. And few other concepts work the same way—a cup in/of flour?

Comment: Thx. Your answer could be applied in this sentence too? "Give me one moment in time.":  'in time' modifies one moment?

Comment: @BEBYGONES Hm, maybe you need to explain more about your question. I answered thinking you were focusing on meaning, but are you focusing on parts of speech? Also, it's true that when you put the phrase into the context of a sentence, there's more difference in meaning. "Give me one moment *of* time" just means "Let me have your attention for a moment." "Give me one moment *in* time" can have only a very abstract and poetical meaning. In both cases, you can leave out "in/of time" effectively.